# ASP.NET ler dados de um POST ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net

Abaixo tem o meu "formulário" que quero enviar para o servidor em um post ajax

```js
$('#ajaxButton').on('click', function () {
            const ajaxFormData = {
                nome: $('#nome').val(),
                zap: $('#whatsapp').val(),
                email: $('#email').val()
            };

            $.ajax({
                url: "/plano-detalhes.aspx",
                data: ajaxFormData,
                type: "POST",
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ajaxForm">
                <h2>Negociar Valores</h2>
                <label>
                    Nome
                    <input id="nome" type="text"/>
                </label>
                <label>
                    Whatsapp
                    <input id="whatsapp" type="text" />
                </label>
                <label>
                    e-mail
                    <input id="email" type="text"/>
                </label>

    <button id="ajaxButton">Enviar</button>
 </div>
```

O problema é que não sei como coletar esses dados enviados na página aspx, veja o que estou tentando abaixo:

```
Request r = new Request();
if (r.isPost)
    {
        try
        {
            dictionary<string, string> ajaxData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> n in r.data)
            {
                ajaxData.Add(n.Key, n.Value);
            }
            //apenas para eu tentar ler
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(ajaxData.toString());
        }
        catch(Exeption e)
        {
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(e);      
        }
    }
```

Sou novo em C# ASP.NET, vim de um background de javascript, não consegui encontrar alguma forma de ler os dados que estou enviando.

agradeço desde já

Comment: O que você está usando? webforms ou mvc?

Comment: webforms, e neste caso não posso enviar direto pelo formulário normal, pq se não da refresh na página e, eu estou pegando uns dados da página anterior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro você tem que habilitar na página ou na master page o page methods:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptmanager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
```

Depois criar uma classe para representar o objeto:

```
 public class Pessoa {
     public string nome {get;set;}
     public string zap {get;set;}
     public string email {get;set;}
 }
```

E depois na página criar o web method:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GravarPessoa(Pessoa pessoa)
{
   var nome = pessoa.nome
}
```

No endereço do post deve ter o nome do método:

```
 url: "/plano-detalhes.aspx/GravarPessoa"
```

Lembrando que o web método é statico